# SQL Check if the User has IN and Out

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help getting the User which has an 'IN' and 'Out' in Column isIN. If the user has an IN and OUT do not select them in the list. I need to select the user who has only had an IN. Please I need help. Thanks in advance.

This is the table:

```
| Users              |  IsIN |
|:------------------:|:-----:|
| MHYHDC61TMJ907867  |  IN   |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907867  |  OUT  |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907922  |  IN   | 
| MHYHDC61TMJ907922  |  OUT  |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907923  |  IN   |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907923  |  OUT  |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907924  |  IN   |  - I need to get only this row
| MHYHDC61TMJ907925  |  IN   |
| MHYHDC61TMJ907925  |  OUT  | 
| MHYHDC61TMJ908054  |  IN   |  - I need to get only this row
| MHYHDC61TMJ908096  |  IN   |  - I need to get only this row
| MHYHDC61TMJ908109  |  IN   |  - I need to get only this row
```

Need to get the result like

```
| Users              | IsIN |
|:------------------:|:-----:|
| MHYHDC61TMJ907924  |  IN   | 
| MHYHDC61TMJ908054  |  IN   |  
| MHYHDC61TMJ908096  |  IN   |  
| MHYHDC61TMJ908109  |  IN   |
```

I tried using this query and sample query below but it doesn't work.

```
select s.[Users], s.[isIn] [dbo].[tblIO] s
where not exists (
    select 1
    from [dbWBS].[dbo].[tblIO] s2
    where s2.[Users] = s.[Users] and s2.isIn = 'IN'
);
```

Comment: select * from user where isIN like '%IN%' and isIN not like '%OUT%'

Comment: SQL LIKE is not the answer. It gets the users who have an IN and OUT in the column. Do you have any idea to get this?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? I have seen this exact question posted before on this site. A hint would be consider window functions.

Comment: As an aside if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: I get stuck in getting the users without IN and OUT. I tried to used IF Exist or IS Equal but doesn't work.

Comment: Please add what you have tried to the question.

Comment: I already edit my question, sir. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You don't appear to have a `FROM` in your attempt, also please don't keep removing the `T-SQL` tag, when you are using SQL + SQL Server you are using T-SQL i.e. SQL Servers variant of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from sample s
where not exists (select 1
                  from sample s2
                  where s2.user = s.user and s2.inout = 'OUT'
                 );
```

If you want only users that meet the condition (and not the full rows):

```
select user
from sample s
group by user
having min(inout) = max(inout) and min(inout) = 'IN';
```

Comment: It is on the same table not on another table.

Comment: @kirbyhipona Gordon's solution **is** using the same table. He has just aliased the tables, which you should always do, but is critical to do when accessing the same table twice so you know which instance you are referencing.

Comment: @kirbyhipona . . . Huh?  I don't understand your comment at all.  This query only refers to one table.

Comment: @kirbyhipona . . . Is there a reason you keep switching back and forth between the accepted answers?  To be clear . . . the first query here returns the full rows because that is what the question asks for.

Comment: yes. i like the query. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that an `'OUT'` `IsIn` must be always preceded by an `'IN'` record, you could use a query like this:

```
select s.Users, 'IN' as IsIn
from sample s
group by s.Users
having count(distinct s.IsIn) = 1
```

Comment: I think this is the right thing. Thank you si much